# Is there any conflict here? \subfloat cannot use \label!

Tags: captions, subfloats, labels, subcaption, figure-placement

I want to put 3 subplots in latex using subfloat, I refer to the example and write as follows, the picture can be displayed normally.

```
\begin{figure*}[!t]
    \centering
    \subfloat[caption fig1a]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{./Fig/Fig1a.png}}
    \hfil
    \subfloat[caption fig1b]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{./Fig/Fig1b.png}}
    \hfil
    \subfloat[caption fig1c]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{./Fig/Fig1c.png}}
    \caption{caption fig1}
   \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure*}
```

However, when I add a \label to each subgraph:

```
\subfloat[caption fig1a]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{./Fig/Fig1a.png}\label{fig:1a}}
```

or this:

```
\subfloat[caption fig1a \label{fig:1a}]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{./Fig/Fig1a.png}}
```

an error is reported as:

```
Undefined control sequence. ...cs[width=0.32\textwidth]{./Fig/Fig1a.png}}
```

The package I used are as follow:

```
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
```

***Here is a minimal example. I found I can refer it, but it still raise a error.***

```
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
        T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!t]
    \centering
    \subfloat[caption fig1a]{\rule{4cm}{4cm}\label{fig:fig1a}}
    \hfil
    \subfloat[caption fig1b]{\rule{4cm}{4cm}\label{fig:fig1b}}
    \hfil
    \subfloat[caption fig1c]{\rule{4cm}{4cm}\label{fig:fig1c}}
    \caption{caption fig1}
    \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure*}

balabalabla \ref{fig:fig1a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

***Hi, guys. I found that there could really be a package conflict.***
If I use the following minimum case, I can use \label normally

```
%\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{stfloats}
%\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
%\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}
%\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
%       T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
%\usepackage{balance}
%\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

%%%%%% Using the following package will not report an error %%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
%\begin{figure*}[!t]
%   \centering
%   \subfloat[caption fig1a]{\rule{4cm}{4cm}\label{fig:fig1a}}
%   \hfil
%   \subfloat[caption fig1b]{\rule{4cm}{4cm}\label{fig:fig1b}}
%   \hfil
%   \subfloat[caption fig1c]{\rule{4cm}{4cm}\label{fig:fig1c}}
%   \caption{caption fig1}
%   \label{fig:fig1}
%\end{figure*}


\begin{figure*}[!t]
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\rule{4cm}{4cm}%
        \label{fig_first_case}}
    \hfil
    \subfloat[]{\rule{4cm}{4cm}%
        \label{fig_second_case}}
    \caption{Dae. Ad quatur autat ut porepel itemoles dolor autem fuga. Bus quia con nessunti as remo di quatus non perum que nimus. (a) Case I. (b) Case II.}
    \label{fig_sim}
\end{figure*}


balabalabla \ref{fig_second_case}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using both `subfig` and `subcaption` at the same time?

Comment: Additionally I do not get any errors running your example and the example with `\label` by the subfloat text works fine. Thus provide a proper minimal example

Comment: The example compiles with out errors for me on TeXLive 2023. Can you provide the log file as well?

Comment: Try if it works, if you load also the nameref package.

Comment: In section 11 on page 26 of the [`subcaption` documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) (it's called "The `\subfloat` command") it says versions 1.3 and above overload the command to maintain compatibility. Is this relevant?

Comment: Also, I found removing the `subfig` package removes the error and doesn't seem to break anything else. Is `subfig` necessary?

Comment: @ My TexLive is also 2023, I don't know which log file you mean, but I copied the log.

Sorry, It's too long, I don't know how to upload it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, What's mean of nameref package?

Comment: simply add `\usepackage{nameref}`.

Comment: @Someone which version do you mean? the TexLive, or else? And I follow you suggestion removed the subfig, it works. But it's really weird, isn't it? I checked my latex again, and I found that I didn't seem to use subfig, but I think this issue can still be discussed, and it can give some experience to poor guy like me

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I follow you advice added the nameref package, but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you using miktex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, I using TexLive 2023

Comment: then update. It works fine for me in a current texlive, I only get an error in miktex which has some older package versions.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My TexLive version info is:

TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023)
kpathsea version 6.3.5
Copyright 2023 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.

It should be the latest version.

Comment: the question is which version of the caption package you use. I have `caption 2023/07/31 v3.6n`.

Comment: To be fair, though, I am using Overleaf, which seems not to know what `IEEEtran` even is.

Comment: overleaf doesn't have texlive 2023 yet, they are using texlive 2022.